# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading $$material) at ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fable-f#

```
ThemeProvider.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$material')
at ThemeProvider (ThemeProvider.js:16:23)
at Main.fs.js:21:13
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
  "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.0.1",
  "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.1",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
  "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
  "@mui/material": "^5.14.5",
  "@mui/styles": "^5.14.5",
  "@mui/system": "^5.14.4",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
  "use-sync-external-store": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
  "vite": "^4.1.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=18"
}
```

code failing on the return line:

```
import * as BlendedLearning$002Emodule from "./Components/pages/BlendedLearning.module.css";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme as createTheme_1 } from "@mui/material/styles";
import * as icons_material from "@mui/icons-material";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { singleton, empty } from "./fable_modules/fable-library.4.0.1/List.js";
import { createElement } from "react";
import { App } from "./Components/SampleComponents.fs.js";
import { Interop_reactApi } from "./fable_modules/Feliz.2.6.0/./Interop.fs.js";
import { run } from "./Components/SampleElmish.fs.js";


export const createTheme = createTheme_1;

export const tp = ThemeProvider;


export const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("feliz-app"));

export const defaultTheme = createTheme(empty());

root.render(tp(singleton((() => {
    const elems = [createElement(App, null)];
    return ["children", Interop_reactApi.Children.toArray(Array.from(elems))];
})())));

run();
```

I can't find anything consistent with `$$material` being a problem in theme provider initialization. I've commented out the `createTheme` parts and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized it was because I missed adding `export default theme` in my theme.ts file.

Hope it helps

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35760133)

Answer (score -1):

This was a consequence of using Fable's `import` instead of `createElement`.

`import` worked with an anonymous record
`createElement` worked with a list of `IReactProperty` which is proper